# Проблема при установке q4os

Tags: linux

Пытаюсь установить Q4OS, и при открытии Q4OS Installer пишет:

> Warning: /run/live/medium not mounted, please mount it prior to run
> the install process

Да, здесь написано смонтировать эту папку перед установкой, но папка смонтирована. По крайней мере, так говорит встроенный файловый менеджер.

После начала установки, выводит это:

> Bad unsquash configuration
> The source filesystem
> "/run/live/medium/live/filesystem.squashfs" does mote exist

При загрузке в failsafe просто зависает.
На этапе загрузки livecd тоже что-то говорит, про неполадки с файлами.

Из-за чего это может быть? Как это решить?

Comment: И в чём состоит вопрос?

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил

Comment: Так в итоге система устанавливается, только варнинги мозолят глаза? Или не устанавливается? Тогда должны быть ошибки ещё. Вот тут смотрели https://dai-trying.com/tutorials/install-q4os-from-live-desktop/?

Comment: Не устанавливается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась просто перезаписью образа

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/507756)

Comment: @LaravelKensin, у меня есть возможность отмечать ответы только через сутки, я непременно отмечу ответ но через 5 часов.